# Android package folder

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am new to android. I using emulator for my development right now , I want to go to my application folder and see what files are there , how can I do that  ?

Secondly , I have heard that I need to root the device otherwise i  cant access it . what  does rooted means ? how can i root emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to understand, you want to view the files of your application on the emulator itself? So, for example, you're storing an XML, or similar file, on the emulator and want to see if it's stored correctly by viewing the file?

If this is the case, checkout DDMS - it comes with the SDK and lets you explore the files for your application on hardware and the emulator. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

You do not need to root your phone for Android development.